# Is Krishna putting fighting over peacekeeping in BG 2 - 31?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, war

https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/2/verse/31

> स्वधर्ममपि चावेक्ष्य न विकम्पितुमर्हसि |
> धर्म्याद्धि युद्धाच्छ्रेयोऽन्यत्क्षत्रियस्य न विद्यते || 31||

> BG 2.31: Besides, considering your duty as a warrior, you should not waver. Indeed, for a warrior, there is no better engagement than fighting for upholding of righteousness.

Here is a modern general, William Tecumseh Sherman

> "I am tired and sick of war. Its glory is all moonshine. It is only those who have neither fired a shot nor heard the shrieks and groans of the wounded who cry aloud for blood, for vengeance, for desolation. War is hell."

Was the notion of using armies for peacekeeping unknown at the time of the Mahabharata?

Comment: @S K - Yudhishtira is a very emotional man. That's why he is saying things like that. Krishna's counsel was correct. The Kauravas through their own actions had brought destruction on themselves.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do peacekeeping in a real situation. Let us take a look at the current situation in Ukraine. Would Russia agree to peacekeeping? Could Adolf Hitler be stopped through peacekeeping? There are situations where fighting is necessary to stop the victory of adharma. The blame for the mayhem due to the fighting is borne by the aggressor. An example would be the 55 million people killed during the second world war. The blame for the colossal amount of deaths is borne by Adolf Hitler and Tojo of Japan. There would have been no deaths if Hitler and Tojo had not started attacking many countries. Self defense may sometimes be necessary. This is what was pointed out by Lord Krishna in his retort to Duryodhana.

> "'Vasudeva said, "**Thou, O son of Gandhari, hast been slain with thy
> brothers, sons, kinsmen, friends, and followers, only in consequence
> of the sinful path in which thou hast trod!** Through thy evil acts
> those two heroes, Bhishma and Drona, have been slain! Karna too hath
> been slain for having imitated thy behaviour! Solicited by me, O fool,
> thou didst not, from avarice, give the Pandavas their paternal share,
> acting according to the counsels of Shakuni! Thou gavest poison to
> Bhimasena! Thou hadst, also, O thou of wicked understanding,
> endeavoured to burn all the Pandavas with their mother at the palace
> of lac! On the occasion also of the gambling, thou hadst persecuted
> the daughter of Yajnasena, while in her season, in the midst of the
> assembly! Shameless as thou art, even then thou becamest worthy of
> being slain! Thou hadst, through Subala's son well-versed in dice,
> unfairly vanquished the virtuous Yudhishthira who was unskilled in
> gambling! For that art thou slain! Through the sinful Jayadratha
> again, Krishna was on another occasion persecuted when the Pandavas,
> her lords, had gone out hunting towards the hermitage of Trinavindu!
> Causing Abhimanyu, who was a child and alone, to be surrounded by
> many, thou didst slay that hero. It is in consequence of that fault, O
> sinful wretch, that thou art slain! **All those unrighteous acts that
> thou sayest have been perpetrated by us, have in reality been
> perpetrated by thee in consequence of thy sinful nature! Thou didst
> never listen to the counsels of Brihaspati and Usanas! Thou didst
> never wait upon the old! Thou didst never hear beneficial words!
> Enslaved by ungovernable covetousness and thirst of gain, thou didst
> perpetrate many unrighteous acts! Bear now the consequences of those
> acts of thine!"**

**Mahabharata Shalya Parva Section 61**

Comment: @S K - what makes one a Kshatriya is fighting for Dharma. The Pandavas tolerated numerous injustices by Kauravas. They were also only demanding Indraprastha and not Hastinapura. Indraprastha rightfully belong to Pandavas alone. They only went to war once all options of peace failed.

Answer (score 0):

Sherman's strategy is a subject of debate /opinionativeness.It had
inflicted a significant damage to   infrastructure and resources of civilians, along the way of his march with his militia.The goal of this strategy was to demoralize civilians by creating a  humanitarian crisis , It was overly harsh and indiscriminate, causing unnecessary suffering and destruction, thereby weakening the morale of civilians, for the purpose of averting the war.

According to Hindu dharma One who has the military advantage would choose to perform Rajasuya , to become an emperor /benefit (drishta(seen) adhrishta(unseen) phala) . Kshatriya dharma forbids inflicting pain on civilians with hostile intent .The battle is always  only among warriors, otherwise it is considered cowardice. Shermans strategy is against the diginity of any Kshatriya king of past , who were unlike their contemporaries (current rulers)

Sri Krishna is beyond any comparison as He is God Himself. He is Yogeshwara, who had already destroyed Duryodhana and others in the causal world , which is sure to reflect in this empirical word. So says Lord  **nimitta-mātraṁ bhava savya-sāchin**(Gita 11.33)(be an instrument of My work, O ambidextrous)

Duryodhana refused an iota of land to Pandavas , in the process of peace making by Sri Krishna.as it is he who was vehement in waging the war .

Vishaya(subject matter) of Bhagavad Gita ,is not vested in proposing a dharma shastra , as it is not a dharma shaastra grantha. Any appearance of dharma shaastra in Gita is attributed only  to the original dharma shaastra grantha ,and thus any such occurrence is known as **anuvaada**

Sri Krishna reminds Arjuna of his social duty according to dharma shaastra, as resorting to ascetism before true renunciation is futile.

[image]

Comment: @S K - Pandavas did try numerous times to peacefully resolve the conflict. Duryodhan and Kauravas however refused a peaceful solution each time. So it's not the Pandavas fault that the war happened. People like Duryodhan and karna are the most responsible for the war. They caused their own destruction.

Comment: @S K - Pandavas were demanding return of Indraprastha. Kauravas has no claim over Indraprastha. It was a kingdom build from scratch by Pandavas and Krishna. Karna is evil. TV serials glorify him. He is the one who due to jealousy constantly instigated Duryodhana towards war. Abhimanyu was killed unfairly. He was surrounded and attacked by all warriors even after he lost his weapons. Even before his final fight with Dusshana's son, Abhimanyu was stated to be resembling a porcupine because his body was filled with arrows.